# Canvas кладет все Images из List на координаты первого Image

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Есть List, каждый image из которого я кладу на рандомные координаты в canvas.
Проблема в том что, первое и второе изображение отображаются нормально, а все последующие, отображаются под вторым

Вот код:

```
        public void Go()
        {
            foreach(var image in Images)
            {
                Image img = new Image
                {
                    Source = image
                };

                img.Height = 250;

                img = SetLocation(img);

                MyCanvas.Children.Add(img);
            }

        }

        private Image SetLocation(Image image)
        {
            var rnd = new Random(); 

            Canvas.SetLeft(image, rnd.Next(0 , 1080 ));
            Canvas.SetTop(image, rnd.Next(0 , 720 ));

            return image;
        }
```

В результате, из коллекции из 5 картинок, отображаются только 2, а остальные 3 находятся стопкой друг на друге под какой-то из этих двух.
С чем это связано вообще?  Спасибо
[image: 1]

Comment: Вы `Canvas` для каких то специальных задач выбрали или просто так? Может вам стоит использовать какой то контрол, который может вывести поочередно элементы? К примеру можно взять `WrapPanel`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Ну, сама задача сделать коллаж из фото, если это не решится, придет другой контрол брать

Comment: Посмотрите, какие у вас получаются случайные числа. Скорее всего, они не случайные. Как минимум сделайте rnd членом класса, вынесите его из функции